# option beforeShowDay is not recognized

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using  Bootstrap datepickers

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

it's working fine but it get error when i try to used beforeShowDay  option 
the Error i got in console is

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: option beforeShowDay is not recognized!
```

i have try lot try but can't get sucess

my HTML is

```
group date' *ngIf="ordertiming" style="margin: 0 0 11px">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date1" autocomplete="off" #myTimeSets (blur)="getTimeData(myTimeSets)">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
```

my TS is

```
 public datePickerEnable(){
        this.getKitchenDetail();
        setTimeout(()=> {
            var mind = new Date();
            var afterday = mind.setDate(mind.getDate() + this.newrestaurantsdetail.preorderforlaterafterdays);
            var countday = this.newrestaurantsdetail.preorderforlaterafterdays + (this.newrestaurantsdetail.preorderforlatertodays -1);
            var todayDate = new Date().getDate();
            $('#date1').datetimepicker({format:'YYYY-MM-DD',  beforeShowDay: function(d) {
                var day = d.getDay();
                return [(day != 0 && day != 3)];
            },minDate: afterday, maxDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(todayDate + countday))});
            $('#date1').val('');
        }, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datepicker - beforeShowDay not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743519/datepicker-beforeshowday-not-working)

Comment: i have try above thing but i doesn't work for me

Comment: It would be useful if you create a working example of the problem, for us to test.

Comment: Not a css question